# PHP: Get width in pixel of text including "normal" text and emoji's

Tags: php, string, measure, multibyte

I want to trim a given text at a given number of pixels.

To achieve this, I loop through the length of the text and with each loop, I add the next character and measure the string with the help of the method `imagettfbbox`. - This works fine for me on "normal text's" e.g. like this posting. ;)

But if I add some emoji's to my text, the length is even shorter than expected. I think this is because emojis encoded with more than 1 byte. - 
That's why, I'm using `mb_strwidth` and `mb_substr`.

The method `imagettfbbox` expects a font-file to measure the given string. This font is able to display my emoji's.

Here's my code

```
$Line = " Garden,  Clock, some other things";
$MaxLength = 100; // Pixel

// Start looping through the line, start with 15 characters
for ( $Len = 15; $Len < mb_strwidth($Line); $Len++ ) {

   // Grep x Chars from line
   $NewLine = mb_substr($Line, 0, $Len);

   // Measure string
   $FontBox = imagettfbbox(12, 0, "fonts/OpenSansEmoji.ttf", $NewLine);
   $TextWidth = $FontBox[2];

   // Compare measured string with given max length
   if ( $TextWidth > $MaxLength ) {
      $Line = mb_substr($Line, 0, $Len - 2) . "...";
      break;
   }
}

$Line = NewLine;
```

Expample lines

```
" Garden,  Clock, some other things"
" Gaaaaaaaaaaaardeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeen"
"mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm"
"iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
"erufgbwuiergbvfuipwervbpiuwebvruiwbevuibwüeriuvbwieuörvböwieuvbr"
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T4VY.png)

As you can see, the more emoji's i use, the shorter the line.

Kind regards from a non native speaker. :)

Comment: Does this problem occur with other fonts? I am suspicious that OpenSansEmoji might have false information about its Emoji widths.